# Can Chrome browser use same ip for proxy BUT different username/password combination per tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, proxy

I have a very big issue with Chrome browser and a custom made extension. I want the extension to connect to different websites by using same ip-address:port, but different username:password combinations per tab.

Problem is that after i visit one site via this extension, then Chrome remembers only the first username:password combination and then uses it for the next website.

Example (what i want to achieve):

Tab1:www.google.com is matched with proxy: 1.1.1.1:3028 username1:password1 Tab2:www.yahoo.com is matched with proxy: 1.1.1.1:3028 username2:password2 Tab3:www.bing.com is matched with proxy: 1.1.1.1:3028 username3:password3

What i get: After opening Tab1: google.com - proxy: 1.1.1.1:3028 username1:password1 Tab2:www.yahoo.com is matched with proxy: 1.1.1.1:3028 username1:password1 Tab3:www.bing.com is matched with proxy: 1.1.1.1:3028 username1:password1

So the issue is that now when i visit www.google.com through proxy: 1.1.1:3028 username1:password1, then this username:pass combination is remembered in Chrome! So when i then visit www.yahoo.com, the proxy server will be again 1.1.1.1:3028 but instead if username2:password2, Chrome remembers and uses again username1:password1 .

Can please someone guide me what i need to research to be able to edit this extension to work properly? I do not need to be spoon fed, just to know what command i should research OR if the thing i want is possible to be achieved at all (Chrome to push somehow new username/password per tab)?

Thanks and please do not hate me if this is lame question, i do not have previous experience with Chrome so i just stumbled upon this issue.

Comment: What is this extension for? ( redirecting passwords to a proxy :0? )

Comment: @Jonasw - the extension is to auto use proxy per URL pattern. I have a few websites i am using regularly but need proxy for each of them, problem is i need to use different user/password combinations for each as there are limitations in proxy usernames, but the proxy IP is same.

Comment: @mike510a - this is what i have now in code - please see here i have pasted the proxy part as no space in comment.. (http://pastebin.com/KUwVD17a)